# How to add a column constraint in Hibernate Entity

Tags: hibernate, constraints, hibernate-mapping

I am creating an in memory  HSQL database with createin my hibernate.cfg.xml
and mapping a User entity.How can i set a constraint on first name to only accept alphabets or gender to only accept "M" or "F"? or do i have to validate before updating the database?`

```
    @Entity
        @Table(name = "User",uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "ID")})
        @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
        public class User implements Serializable
        {
          @Id
          @GeneratedValue
          @Column(name = "ID",unique = true, nullable = false)
          private long id;

          @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME",unique = false, nullable = false, length = 100)
          private String firstName;
         @Column(name = "GENDER",unique = false, nullable = false)
         private String gender;
```

Comment: got it done using hibernate validator http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/hibernate/hibernate-validator-example/

Comment: Great -- post an answer here detailing your solution, then in a few days you'll be able to accept it and earn the rep